# Nested list - array - remove - append

Tags: python

I'm learning on Hackerrank a problem called Nested list, here is the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem.

I wanted to ask why when I used .remove, it didn't work. This is the part where I used .remove:

```
# for i in range(len(scoreList)):  
#     if scoreList[i] == minScore:
#         scoreList.remove(scoreList[i]);
#         nameList.remove(nameList[i]);
# remove doesn't work. why?
```

However, when I used .append, it worked well. I don't understand why. Could you take a look and let me know where is the problem please? Thank you.

Here is my solution, which is accepted:

```
nestedList = [];

for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    name = raw_input()
    score = float(raw_input())
    nestedList.append([name, score]);      
        
# print len(nestedList);
# print nestedList[1];
# print nestedList[1][0];

# for inner in nestedList:
#      for value in inner:
#          print value

nameList = [];
scoreList = [];

for i in range(len(nestedList)):
    currentName = nestedList[i][0];
    currentScore = nestedList[i][1];
    nameList.append(currentName);
    scoreList.append(currentScore);

minScore = min(scoreList);   

scoreNotMin = [];
nameNotMin = [];

for i in range(len(scoreList)):
    if scoreList[i] != minScore:
        scoreNotMin.append(scoreList[i]);
        nameNotMin.append(nameList[i]);

# for i in nameNotMin:
#     print i;
# ok check append works.


# for i in range(len(scoreList)):  
#     if scoreList[i] == minScore:
#         scoreList.remove(scoreList[i]);
#         nameList.remove(nameList[i]);
# remove doesn't work. why?        

            
secondMin = min(scoreNotMin);
# print secondMin

output = [];
for i in range(len(scoreNotMin)):
    if scoreNotMin[i] == secondMin: 
        output.append(nameNotMin[i]);
output.sort();
for i in output:
    print i;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting an error or it just doesn't work as expected?

Comment: It has the Runtime Error :( Your Output (stdout) ~ no response on stdout ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the length of your list is changing while running through the list, because your are using the name `nameList` in this line `nameList.remove(nameList[i])` twice.

I would guess you get a `list index out of range` error.

Please try this minimal example:

```
# this works
nameList = ['a', 'b']
nameList.remove(nameList[1])
>>> ['a']
# here you run into an error
nameList = ['a', 'b']
for i in range(len(nameList)):
    nameList.remove(nameList[i])
```